# Starting service from broadcast receiver causing app crash

Tags: android, service, bluetooth, broadcastreceiver

I am trying to start a simple `service` which will show some `toasts` only when a system broadcast of `bluetooth on` and `off` is received .
My broadcastReceiver class :

```
public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String bluth=arg1.getAction();
        if(bluth.equals(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED)){
            if(arg1.getIntExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_STATE, -1) 
                    == BluetoothAdapter.STATE_ON){
                SharedPreferences sp=arg0.getSharedPreferences(prefs,
                        Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                Editor ed=sp.edit();
                ed.putInt(count, counter);
                ed.commit();
                counter++;
                Toast.makeText(arg0, "Bluetooth on  "+sp.getInt(count,0), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                i=new Intent(arg0,NotifyTimer.class);
                arg0.startService(i);
                //i=new Intent(arg0,Indicators.class);
                //i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                //arg0.startActivity(i);
                //Indicators.on.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }else if(arg1.getIntExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_STATE, -1) 
                    == BluetoothAdapter.STATE_OFF){
                arg0.stopService(i);

            }else if(arg1.getIntExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_STATE, -1) 
                    == BluetoothAdapter.STATE_TURNING_OFF){

            }else if(arg1.getIntExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_STATE, -1) 
                    == BluetoothAdapter.STATE_TURNING_ON){

            }
        }
```

My service class code:

```
public class NotifyTimer extends Service {

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate();
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Service created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDestroy();
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Service destroyed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        /*NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder=new NotificationCompat.Builder(getBaseContext());
        mBuilder.setColor(Color.RED);
        mBuilder.setContentTitle("Bluetooth opened ");
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(this.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

         mNotificationManager.notify(0, mBuilder.build()); 
        mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
    */
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Service started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

}
```

Now whenever I run my code I cannot see **service** `toast` and whenever I close the bluetooth the app crashes !

Can anybody find out the reason ?

Comment: did u registered service in manifest?

Comment: Oh no! thnks but let me try frst !

Comment: We register **service** like this  ` <service android:name=".NotifyTimer" />` ?

Comment: It is still crashing when I off the bluetooth

Comment: u can use .NotifyTimer if the service class lies under same package name provided in manifest,otherwise use full path to service class

Comment: pls show me the error log trace

Comment: I cannot because I am running it in my phone !

Comment: Not in emulator as emulator doesn't have bluetooth

Comment: But I can tell you that when I on the bluetooth toast message related to `service` is shown .It only crashes when I close the app !

Comment: Try running app to device from IDE and show some logs

Comment: I mean bluetooth not app !

Comment: `09-17 15:01:14.742: E/AndroidRuntime(19210): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-17 15:01:14.742: E/AndroidRuntime(19210): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.example.bluetoothcount.BroadCast: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-17 15:01:14.742: E/AndroidRuntime(19210):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2557)
09-17 15:01:14.742: E/AndroidRuntime(19210):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:162)


09-17 15:01:14.742: E/AndroidRuntime(19210): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
`

Comment: its clear that a null pointer exception is arises in on recive method of ur broadcast reciver

Comment: try debuging the code,and find where the null value comes

Comment: `else if(arg1.getIntExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_STATE, -1) 
                    == BluetoothAdapter.STATE_OFF){
                arg0.stopService(i);

            }`

Comment: I think the problem is here see

Comment: may arg1.getIntExtra is null

Comment: then what to do ?

Comment: But i don' t think So if it is null then STATE ON will also not work which means the app will crash simply when I switch on the bluetooth !

Comment: i am sure debuging code will give u the solution,find where the null occuers